# Sony Remote Control API for C# Windows Application

Tags: sony

I am trying to create a Windows Application using Sony Remote Control API. Can Anyone help with related Tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

I am actually not aware of any Windows tutorials for the Camera Remote API, but there are a lot of resources out there that could help you create your application. With that being said here are a few things that could help:

- You for sure want to download the SDK and have a look at the documentation. The documentation will show you how to get the proper endpoint urls and then teach you how to use each of the available endpoints for your camera. https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/
- Here are a few projects that use the Camera Remote API that could be helpful:

> This is a windows 10 universal app using the Camera Remote API
>
> https://github.com/locana/locana
>
> This is a python based application that many users have found useful
>
> https://github.com/Bloodevil/sony_camera_api

I hope these resources are helpful. Please let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I am now exploring SDK documentation only. Able to capture pics, just struggling with displaying LiveView on Windows Form, can get live view stream but not able to extract JPEG out of the packet. Working on it, any help?

Comment: Sure thing. Liveview is a bit confusing, but you can start reading the pdf documentation on page 269 to try and get a better understanding of how it works. Also if you can check out this javascript example to get a better idea of how things work. https://github.com/naoyuki-sato/Camera-Remote-API/blob/master/webapp/cameraApp.js::Line 93 , https://github.com/naoyuki-sato/Camera-Remote-API/blob/master/webapp/cameraRemoteApi.js::Line 75.

Comment: This has been upgraded to the Camera Remote SDK located at:
https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/app/sdk/en/

I'm currently implementing this in C# for usage in Unity. I've gotten some of the basic function calls working such as `GetSDKVersion`, `Init` and `Release`, but anything using pointers to class references I'm having problems with implementing them in C#. If anyone else is working on it we can probably chat.